# How to add a package from a later version of an ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and I want to install tesseract-ocr 3.03 via apt-get. I found [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tesseract-ocr) package, which seems like it is for ubuntu 14.  Is there a way to install it without installing the full upgraded operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Download the tar file from the below link and try installing the package. Seems to be working in my machine

https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/archive/3.03-rc1.tar.gz

```
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

Once you finished installing check the installed status using **checkinstall** command instead of make install